AWS Inspector SDK for Java - how to list findings?
I've implemented a simple app which uses AWSK SDK to retrieve Inspector scan findings, but I observe a very strange behavior - the next token has value but the findingArns list is empty. Here's the sample code:
ListFindingsRequest request = ListFindingsRequest.builder().build();
ListFindingsResponse response = inspectorClient.listFindings();

response.hasFindingArns() returns true but the response.findingArns().size() is 0.
Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? Are there any good examples of calling the AWS Inspector from Java?

Well, I enabled wire logging and what I see is that the inspector client sends empty POST request to inspector.us-west-2.amazonaws.com, e.g.: POST / HTTP/1.1 Content-Length: 2 {} and receives back 200 with empty content. This doesn't look right to me, what am I missing? My AWS SDK version is 2.25.15

OK, so as it turns out, Amazon has two APIs, Inspector and Inspector2. I switched to the Inspector2 API and now everything looks good. Here's a sample of the code:
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.inspector2.Inspector2Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.inspector2.model.ListFindingsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.inspector2.model.ListFindingsResponse;

...

Inspector2Client inspectorClient = Inspector2Client.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .httpClientBuilder(
                    ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                )
                .build();

ListFindingsRequest request = ListFindingsRequest.builder().build();
ListFindingsResponse response = inspectorClient.listFindings(request);

This works just fine and returns the expected data. I wish AWS documentation were a bit less confusing and provided at least one example and some explanation of differences between inspector and inspector2.
